# missing mysqld.sock and mysqld in /etc/init.d

Tags: sockets, mysql

I tried today to connect to MySQL server and saw that I did'nt have any mysqld.sock anymore, nowhere.

I tried several ways to get it back, but unsuccessfull. I tried to execut a
`./mysqld.start` in `/etc/init.d`, but it's also missing.

Should I reinstall mysql, or is there a way to get a socket back ?

Answer (score 1):

try using following command

```
service mysql start
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

@Nueva, if that doesn't work, reboot the system. I just had an Ubuntu build on EC2 lose its mysqld.sock file, and a simple reboot solved the problem.

Failing that, I've also heard that forcing the connection via tcp instead of localhost has worked for some people. I tried that, but got nothing.